# Value of JsonObject coming as null in WSO2 EI Log Mediator and Property Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

```
{
  "VendorShipFromAddress": 222,
  "CompanyBillToAddress": 3123,
  "CompanyShipToAddress": 123,
  "LineItems": {
    "LineItem": [
      {
        "LineItemId": "41842203D8B433468CB2151B20377F48",
        "ExpenseTypeCode": "2109"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to print the value of the JSON object in WSO2 MI using the below

```
<log level="full">
    <property expression="json-eval($.VendorShipFromAddress)" name="status1"/>
</log>
```

Ideally the log should print status1 = 222

But I am getting status 1 = (null)

1. Please let me know if I am missing out something
2. Please let me know how can I access the value LineItemId in a property mediator.

This is with regards to WSO2 EI

Comment: Can you show the whole log? With full it should also print the whole body/message right?

Answer (score -1):

Please try `log` level as `custom` like below

```
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="VendorShipFromAddress===" expression="json-eval($.VendorShipFromAddress)"/>
         </log>
```

**To get LineItemId:**

```
<property name="LineItemId" expression="//LineItem/LineItemId/text()"/>
```